# Get all user properties from Microsoft graph

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have an application which has used a local AD to fetch user info. Some customers want to move to the cloud and are using Azure AD. We extended the app to sign users in via owin and now we're fetching users via Microsoft Graph.

However from Microsoft Graph we do not get full user profiles. We want to fetch all properties on users, not just the basic ones.

```
var client = new RestClient(string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}", userEmail));
request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.AddHeader("Authorization", _token.Token);
var reponse = client.Execute(request);
```

This only gives me some information though, for example I don't get 'Department' from this.
Is it possible to configure in azure what should be returned here, if so then where? Or do I need something other than `/users/`?

Different customers might have different special properties that need to be fetched. So the best solution would be to have an endpoint to call and get everything, including special properties not standard in azure ad. After that I can parse it on my side. Is this possible?

The app has permission to read both basic and full profiles. Do I need something more?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour of Graph API, see documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003365#optional-query-parameters) and this extract:

> By default, only a limited set of properties are returned (
> `businessPhones`, `displayName`, `givenName`, `id`, `jobTitle`, `mail`,
> `mobilePhone`, `officeLocation`, `preferredLanguage`, `surname`,
> `userPrincipalName`).
>
> To return an alternative property set, you must specify the desired
> set of user properties using the OData `$select` query parameter. For
> example, to return displayName, givenName, and postalCode, you would
> use the add the following to your query
> `$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode`

You have to specify all fields in the select, as `$select=*` will only output the key fields in Graph API implementation.

So you will not be able to get what you ask (variable custom fields).

More info on the fields of User can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003365#user-entity)

Comment: Ah ok i see. But getting custom fields are not possible at all via microsoft graph?
Can i get them some other way?

Comment: I did not say that you can't get custom fields

Comment: I misunderstood the 'So you will not be able to get..'-part. So I can still get them by putting them in the $select but i cant do a request that returns everything is what you meant?

Comment: If you know the fields name, you can get them. You just can ask for "all fields" without providing their names

Comment: Just to summarize (per Nicolas) - on the user entity type just the base/default set of properties are returned for a standard GET operation.  If you want more than the standard set you need to explicitly ask for the set of properties you want using $select.  $select=* is not supported.  If you are looking for this functionality please request it on UserVoice here:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: Can you get the base fields PLUS specific fields?  I noticed when using $select I JUST get the field I ask for

Comment: @Mike, your question is unclear. As already said in comment, if you imagine getting all fields (base, specific) without knowing the fields names, no that's not possible. If you know all your base and specific fields, just provide them

Comment: @NicolasR - sorry if I was unclear.  I meant, can you get the specified $select field in addition to the base list it originally provides (is, businessPhones, etc.)

Comment: Add the base list items in your select

Comment: If I want to get the company name or thumbnailphoto how would I get that? can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does anyone know how this is achieved in the [PowerShell Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started)?  The same logic is not working for me when trying to return a custom attribute (added via `Azure AD B2C` > `User Attributes`) for all users or a single user, eg:  `Get-MgUser -Property "id,extension_<extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"` or `Get-MgUser -UserId "<user-id>" -Property "id,extension_<extensions-app-application-id>_CompanyName"`.  I have a question [about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75273307).

Answer (score 7):

```
User user = await graphServiceClient
    .Users[emailId]
    .Request()
    .Select(aadUser => new
    {
        aadUser.Id,
        aadUser.UserPrincipalName,
        aadUser.DisplayName,
        aadUser.GivenName,
        aadUser.Surname,
        aadUser.City,
        aadUser.MailNickname,
        aadUser.UserType
    })
    .GetAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I've been able to find all available properties for a user:

1. Go to "Groups"
2. Select "list all groups in my organization"
3. Change the query to filter by a group you know and expand **members**: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mail eq 'aGroup@company.com'&$expand=members`

Now you'll see all the available properties for the users.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated by NicolasR, you must list all the fields you want to retrieve by using the "$select" parameter; if you want, instead, to retrieve the custom fields, you can either add them to the previous parameter (if you know their names) or you can use "$expand=extensions"

Comment: "$expand=extensions" i didnt get anything different by adding this parameter so could you please expand :D

Comment: @ChopLabalagun you can refer to this other question, it should solve your doubts ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925030/get-extended-properties-on-user-using-microsoft-graph

Answer (score 2):

```
function getGraphDataAdvanced($authToken, $urlGraph){
    $url = $urlGraph + '&$count=true'

    $data = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $($authToken)"
        ConsistencyLevel = "eventual"
    } -Uri $url -Method Get)

    $dataList = @()
    $dataList += $data.value

    $url = $data.'@Odata.NextLink'

    while ($null -ne $url){
        Write-Warning 'Retreiving Next Page'

        $data = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{
            Authorization = "Bearer $($authToken)"
            ConsistencyLevel = "eventual"
        } -Uri $url -Method Get)

        $dataList += $data.value
        $url = $data.'@Odata.NextLink'
    }
    return $dataList
}

getGraphDataAdvanced $authToken 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users? $expand=extensions'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find a way to get all Azure AD properties of objects via Powershell MSGraph cmdlets without it truncating at the right edge of the console.

I've discovered that **Format-Custom** triggers vomiting of (apparently) all properties of an object in a huge, alphabetical, indented, and bracketed list.

```
Get-MgUser -filter "startswith(userprincipalname, 'username')" | format-custom
```

The formatted properties of a newly created and unused user account in Azure AD is 13217 lines long.

Answer (score 1):

The 'AzureAD' module would allow for `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId unique.identifier@domain.com | fl` and spit out everything for that user.  It's an incredibly fast and easy way to see what has and has not been set.

Comment: Hi, while this does work, this isn't a good answer because unfortunately, the AzureAD PowerShell module has been marked as deprecated and will be removed in future. It's replacement is the Microsoft Graph Powershell SDK.

Comment: Get-MgUser -UserId user@test.com | Format-List produces the same results as Get-AzureADUser, so this is still relevant.