# How to retrieve all user properties with MS Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Using the [Microsoft Graph quick start guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start), I can get my user object with

```
var one = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

But it only includes values for these properties

```
BusinessPhones       
DisplayName          
GivenName            
Id                   
JobTitle             
Mail                 
OfficeLocation       
Surname              
UserPrincipalName
```

Where the rest are just `null`. However, I expect to see some values in, for example `AboutMe`.

I can retrieve that value specifically with

```
var one = await graphClient.Me.Request().Select("aboutme").GetAsync();
```

But is there a way to get all properties?

I tried

```
var one = await graphClient.Me.Request().Select("").GetAsync();
var one = await graphClient.Me.Request().Select("*").GetAsync();
```

But that doesn't return all properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all user properties from microsoft graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229949/get-all-user-properties-from-microsoft-graph). Also note that you _really_ don't want "everything". Try hitting `beta/me` in Graph Explorer and you'll quickly realize just how many "things" are in "everything". It's a _lot_ of data.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur It's just for testing purposes to see what data is available. When the application is in use we will just get the fields that we need

Comment: Ah, for that just use the `/beta` endpoint. It returns the entire `DirectoryObject` without any filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is not yet? implemented.

The Documentations for the select parameter states:

> In v1.0, some Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject,
>   like user and group, return a limited, default subset of properties on
>   reads. For these resources, you must use $select to return properties
>   outside of the default set.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#select-parameter

This seems to be the reason why a select=* is returning only some directoryObject-properties, as the user-object is derived from the directoryObject.

To access all properties you would need to manually define them in your select-query or alternatively you could adjust the default set for the server to return all properies (not sure if you can define this in the online application settings though).